# CMake add BLAS to project

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to compile a project with dlib & opencv. I am super new to CMake. It needs a BLAS library included. I have ATLAS installed, I've tried a couple things, but not found any that I can get to work. Is there a way to find a BLAS package installed and add it on Linux (Ubuntu 18.04)? Any help would be much appreciated.

Errors

[image]

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <dlib/pixel.h>
#include <dlib/opencv.h>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/image_processing/frontal_face_detector.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    cv::Mat frame, half;
    cv::VideoCapture cap;
    dlib::array2d<dlib::bgr_pixel> dlibFrame;

    try
    {
        cap.open(2);
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    dlib::frontal_face_detector detector;

    try
    {
        std::vector<dlib::rectangle> faces;
        cv::namedWindow("Tracking Window");

        while(cap.isOpened())
        {
             cap >> frame;
             cv::resize(frame,half,cv::Size(),0.5,0.5); 
             dlib::assign_image(dlibFrame,dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel>(half));

             faces = detector(dlibFrame);

             for(size_t i = 0;i < faces.size();++i)
             {
                 auto& r = faces[i];
                 cv::Rect cvr = cv::Rect(r.left(),r.top(),r.width(),r.height());

                 cv::rectangle(half,cvr,cv::Scalar(255,0,0),2);
             }

             cv::imshow("Tracking Window",half); 

             if(cv::waitKey(1) == 27)
                break;
        }
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        cout << e.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cv::destroyAllWindows();

    return 0;
}
```

CMake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0)
project(ObjectTracking VERSION 0.1.0)

include(CTest)
enable_testing()

add_executable(ObjectTracking main.cpp)

find_package(BLAS REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(dlib REQUIRED)

target_link_libraries(ObjectTracking ${OpenCV_LIBS} dlib ${BLAS_LIBRARIES})

set(CPACK_PROJECT_NAME ${PROJECT_NAME})
set(CPACK_PROJECT_VERSION ${PROJECT_VERSION})
include(CPack)
```

Comment: Which LInux distro are you using?  Ubuntu? CentOs?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 CraigS.Anderson

Comment: Please, add **textual** output of the build process into the question post. You may include the image of the "Problems" tab too, but textual error messages is a requirement of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu 18.04, there are the following packages:

- libblas-dev
- libbas3
- libcblas2
- libcublas9.1 (if you have a Nvidia GPU and CUDA?)

I use OpenBLAS, so I'm not positive about which one to use.

An alternative is OpenBLAS.   The repo is at: https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git

To build it:

1. git clone https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git
2. cd OpenBLAS
3. sudo make install

OpenBLAS detects your CPU and creates the appropriate binary.

Comment: I have libblas-dev and openblas installed. However, CMAKE still can't find them :( is there something I need to do to find them?

Comment: I was able to make it work by explicitly specifying OpenBLAS